# C# Japanese morphological analyzers

Tags: c#, nlp, cjk, morphological-analysis

I can't find any Japanese morphological analyzers for C#. Can anyone please suggest one?

Answer (score 1):

I have had experience with Mecab and it works quite well.
You can consume the library in C#: http://pastebin.com/Y1vvE7ZM

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! By the way, what dictionary/corpus do you use with mecab? Do you find the results satisfactory? Also, is there a way to output only lemmas? Thank you.